# how to convert a string with brackets to an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, string

I'm having a problem with this. I have a string that looks like this:

```
coilovers[strut_and_individual_components][complete_strut][][achse]
```

And i want to convert it to to array that looks like this:

```
[coilovers] => Array
(
    [strut_and_individual_components] => Array
    (
        [complete_strut]=> Array
        (
            [1] => Array
            (
                [achse] => some_value     
            )
            [2] => Array
            (
                [achse] => some_value     
            )
        )
    )
)
```

is it possible?

Comment: Sure, what have you tried?

Comment: Please post your try to solve the problem so that we can help you

Comment: preg_match_all("\[(.*?)\]", $string, $matches); tried something with regex but no luck

Comment: It is always not necessary to try if you have a question in your mind. Sometimes people are out of ideas to kick a start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick implementation of a parser that will attempt to parse this string:

```
$input = 'coilovers[strut_and_individual_components][complete_strut][][achse]'; 

$output = array(); 
$pointer = &$output;

while( ($index = strpos( $input, '[')) !== false) {  
    if( $index != 0)  { 
        $key = substr( $input, 0, $index);
        $pointer[$key] = array();
        $pointer = &$pointer[$key];
        $input = substr( $input, $index);
        continue;
    }
    $end_index = strpos( $input, ']'); 
    $array_key = substr( $input, $index + 1, $end_index - 1);
    $pointer[$array_key] = array();
    $pointer = &$pointer[$array_key];
    $input = substr( $input, $end_index + 1);
}

print_r( $output);
```

Essentially, we are iterating the string to find matching `[` and `]` tags. When we do, we take the value within the brackets as `$array_key` and add that into the `$output` array. I use another variable `$pointer` by reference that is pointing to the original `$output` array, but as the iteration goes, `$pointer` points to the last element added to `$output`.

It produces:

```
Array
(
    [coilovers] => Array
        (
            [strut_and_individual_components] => Array
                (
                    [complete_strut] => Array
                        (
                            [] => Array
                                (
                                    [achse] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Note that I've left the implementation of `[]` (an empty array key) and setting the values in the last index (`some_value`) as an exercise to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Well I've found an another answer for it and it looks like this:

```
private function format_form_data(array $form_values) {

    $reformat_array = array();
    $matches = array();
    $result = null;

    foreach($form_values as $value) {
        preg_match_all("/\[(.*?)\]/", $value["name"], $matches);
        $parsed_product_array = $this->parse_array($matches[1], $value["value"]);
        $result = array_push($reformat_array, $parsed_product_array);
    }

    return $result;
}

private function parse_array(array $values, $value) {
    $reformat = array();
    $value_carrier_key = end($values);

    foreach (array_reverse($values) as $arr) {
        $set_value_carrier = array($arr => $reformat);
        if($arr == $value_carrier_key) {
            $set_value_carrier = array($arr => $value);
        }
        $reformat = empty($arr) ? array($reformat) : $set_value_carrier;
    }

    return $reformat; 
}
```

where array $form_values is:

```
Array
(
   [name] => '[coilovers][strut_and_individual_components][complete_strut][][achse]',
   [value] => 'some_value'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

No. If you [evaluate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) the string you will get invalid PHP.

If you want to store a PHP Array as string and get it loaded back as PHP Array, have a look at [serialize](http://pt1.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and [unserialize](http://pt1.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) functions.

Of course you can build an array from your string, but you'll have to write a parser.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I propose:

```
function format_form_data(array $data) {

    $matches = array();
    $result = [];

    foreach($data as $key => $value) {
        preg_match_all("/\[(.*?)\]/", $key, $matches);
        $matches = array_reverse($matches[1]);
        $matches[] =  substr( $key, 0, strpos($key, '['));;

        foreach ($matches as $match) {
            $value = [$match=>$value];
        }

        $result = array_replace_recursive($result, $value);
    }

    return $result;
}
```